# Auditing in JPA which is similar to Hibernate envers

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-envers

Does JPA provides any specification for Auditing entities.

The issue is currently we are using Hibernate envers to audit an entity in our application.
I want to move out of this and implement a solution which is generic across ORM layer. as it is just for auditing purpose I have to use Hibernate API in my application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is anything in the specification but... if you are using the Hibernate implementation of JPA you could likely use the Envers project with your configuration. Had a look and sure enough there is a guide to do so:

[Auditing JPA entities with Hibernate Envers](http://guidogarcia.net/blog/2012/01/25/auditing-jpa-entities-with-hibernate-envers/)

Answer (score 1):

A useful feature in the JPA specification for auditing is [Entity Listeners](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html/listeners.html).
However prior to version 2.1 you could not use injection in them. As of version 2.1 CDI is [supported](http://hantsy.blogspot.gr/2013/12/jpa-21-cdi-support.html)

Hibernate supports JPA 2.1 in version [4.3](http://www.infoq.com/news/2013/12/hibernate-4-3-released)